# Java heap space OutOfMemoryError in pyspark client mode

Tags: pyspark

I am working on pyspark client mode.System configuration are 32 Gb ram and 32 cores.My driver memory is 2048 and executor memory is 2048.Below is my pyspark configuration.

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName(appName) \
.master(master) \
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") \
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "4") \
.config("spark.executor.instances", "5") \
.config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "200") \
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.shuffle.service.index.cache.size", "2048") \
.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseParallelGC") \
.config("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec") \
.config("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking ", "false") \
.config("spark.shuffle.compress", "True") \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "20") \
.config("spark.default.parallelism", "20").config("spark.cleaner.ttl", "60") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
```

when i fetch above 500 000 rows (8 gb) from hive which is in csv format gives the error of **gc limit exceeded**.
Is there any command for checking how much gc is used or how much gc is unused?
Also how to remove this error?

Answer (score 2):

To know the GC details, you can use the below command. Some [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning) for the same

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your driver memory given that you're pulling `8GB` while specifying a `2GB` limit. You can try to configure your `offHeap` as well.

You can manage these Spark memory limits programmatically (by the API).

You can set them while defining the `SparkSession`:

```
spark = (
            SparkSession.builder.master(master_url)
                .config("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
                .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
                .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") 
                .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g")
                .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled",true)
                .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","16g")  
                .getOrCreate()
        )
```

If your workload is the same for all analysis, then editing `spark-defaults.conf` as cited above is the way to go.